# Who is the character you play in Portal?

Tags: portal-series

The character you play in Portal is never named throughout the game.  I can see that it's a female by looking through a portal, but the game always skirts any information about the character (e.g. GlaDOS speaks to you, but cuts out the name by saying *"Subject name here.")*  I understand that Valve did this because they want you, personally to become more immersed in the game, but I think having a **compelling character** with a great story makes a good game even better.

Who is she?  What is her story?

Comment: Actually, part of what made the game compelling is the fact that a lot of things are a mystery to the player.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

She is Chell.

[image]

See [here](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Chell):

> Although Chell's origins are unknown, she was most definitely among the people present during GLaDOS's activation in 200-, as GLaDOS locked down the facility after her activation, letting none escape, or be let in from the outside.

**EDIT**: Visiting [aperturescience.com](http://aperturescience.com/), you can learn that she is the daughter of Cave Johnson (CEO of Aperture Science) and that she was brought there on Bring Your Daughter To Work day.

Comment: _CJohnson_ is scrawled on the wall in the rat-man den of the Companion Cube chamber.  There's a password too, if I'm not mistaken: _Tier3_ I believe.  Anyone know what these do?

Comment: Does anyone know what are those things on her legs?

Comment: @Cray it's an "anti gravity device" (I don't remember the exact name) -- it's what causes her not to break her legs when she falls from incredible heights

Comment: @Juan - they're called heel springs, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Yep - heel springs. "What's wrong with your legs?" - GlaDOS

Comment: @Cray They're a foot-based suit of armor for the portal device, developed after they discovered a reproducible human error problem that caused damage to the valuable equipment: http://laptopmemo.com/2011/04/12/a-new-portal-2-ad-this-time-about-aperture-science-boots/

Comment: Going to Aperturescience.com, it seems they left the Christmas promotion up.  Is there anyway to still access to old site to see this confirmation?

Comment: @Shadur Those are the ones in Portal 2. Very different from the ones Portal 1 uses.

Comment: I was under the impression that she was the adopted daughter of an Aperture Science employee, but not Cave Johnson specifically. He doesn't seem like the paternal type, anyway.